# How to retrieve model data for use inside of another model?

Tags: node.js, ember.js, sails.js

I'm working with an Ember app that ties into a Rails backend through a Sails.js API, and ran into an issue I can't find any similar examples for.

My Messages model has a `sender_id` column, which corresponds with the `id` column in my Users model. There is also a Profile model (belongs to User through `user_id`) that contains the `username` column, which is what I'd like to be able to access through the Messages model as 'senderName' (i.e., `message.senderName`). My models and routes are all hooked up, so I have access to all the data I need and everything displays correctly in the browser aside from my senderName function.

The plan was to look up the Profile object through its `user_id` (using `sender_id`) inside of Messages, then pull the `username` field from there. I've been able to receive Promises back from my Profile query, but from there I'm not sure how/if I can access the actual `username` field. Is there a way to do this, or am I trying to fit a square peg into a round hole?

I also tried accessing `username` by looking up the User object first (`this.store.find('user')`, etc.) and using my Rails associations for `user.profile.username`, but that didn't work either.

**Models:**

```
  App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    sender_id : DS.attr('number'),
    content : DS.attr('string'),
    senderName: function() {
      var id = this.get('sender_id');
      var profile = this.store.find('profile', {user_id: id}).then(function() {
      console.log(profile);
      // What next? profile.username doesn't work
    })
  }.property('sender_id')
});

App.Profile = DS.Model.extend({
   user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
   username : DS.attr('string'),
   user_id : DS.attr('number')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    profile: DS.belongsTo('profile', { async: true }),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="messages/index">
    <div class="small-12 column">
        {{#each message in model}}
            <p>From: {{message.senderName}}</p>
            <p>Content: {{message.content}}</p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Here's an example of the promises I'm receiving back in the browser console:

```
Promise {_id: 93, _label: undefined, _state: undefined, _result: undefined, _subscribers: Array[0]…}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting the question correct, you are having trouble accessing the fields in the model? If so, try:

`profile.get('username')`

Comment: Yes, that's right. I tried `profile.get('username')`, though, and got a "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: undefined is not a function" error in return. I thought maybe that's happening because the promise returns an array, but `profile[0]` comes back undefined.

Comment: Its possible that your code is running before the "profile" has loaded - have you looked into using a Promise? Check out the Ember.RSVP stuff.

Comment: It's also worth experimenting in your console window - put some breakpoints in, probably just after the model gets loaded, and try the command I gave you from there

Answer (score 0):

You're really overcomplicating this :-)

Message also belongs to sender, why did you define sender_id as a number?

If you delete `senderName` and change the `sender_id` property to:

```
sender: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true }),
```

You can use `message.get('sender.profile.username')`.  I think your main issue here is that you're trying to do an async operation in the computed property, which is a no-no.  You can alias the senderName if you like, via `senderName: Ember.computed.alias('sender.profile.username')` if you end up using it a lot.